# Creating a calendar in Javascript (Html)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a calendar and I have two problems.

1. The months will not display as text, but rather as numbers.
2. The days also won't update when I change the months. Months have different amounts of days and thus the amount of days in the days select needs to update based on the choice in the month select.

[image]

Day/Month/Year format.

Here is the html code:

```
<form>
  <select id="day" name="day">
  </select>

  <select id ="month" onchange = "changeDays(this)" name="month" >
  </select>

  <select id="year" name="year">
  </select>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
setCalendar('day',1, 31, false); 
setCalendar('month',1, 12, false); 
setCalendar('year',1910, 2017, false); 

function setCalendar(id, min, max, logic){

if(logic){
removeOptions(id); 
}

var monthsarray = ["January", "February","March" ,"April" ,"May" ,"June" ,"July" ,"August" ,"September", "October", "November" , "December"];  

for  (i = min; i <= max; i++){
select = document.getElementById(id); 
var opti = document.createElement("option"); 
opti.value = i; 
opti.text = id === "day" || "year" ? i.toString() : monthsarray[i-1]; 
select.add(opti); 
}

}


function changeDays(SelectObject){

switch(SelectObject){
case 1: 
//January
 setCalendar('day',1,31,true); 
break; 
case 2: 
//February
 setCalendar('day',1,28,true); 
break; 
case 3:
//March 
 setCalendar('day',1,31,true); 
break; 
case 4:
//April  
 setCalendar('day',1,30,true); 
break; 
case 5:
//May 
 setCalendar('day',1,31,true); 
break; 
case 6: 
//June
 setCalendar('day',1,30,true); 
break; 
case 7: 
//July
 setCalendar('day',1,31,true); 
break; 
case 8:  
//August
 setCalendar('day',1,31,true); 
break;
case 9: 
//September
 setCalendar('day',1,30,true); 
break; 
case 10: 
//October
 setCalendar('day',1,31,true); 
break; 
case 11: 
//November
 setCalendar('day',1,30,true); 
break; 
case 12:  
//December
 setCalendar('day',1,31,true); 
break;  
}

}

function removeOptions(selectObject)
{
    var i;
    for(i = selectObject.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        selectObject.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `id === "day" || "year"` is wrong: should be `id === "day" || id === "year"`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use one of the zillion already existing plugins for that job?

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass `this` as an argument to that function. It should already be accessible.

Comment: what about leap years? Not hard to find how many days in a specific month and get rid of all of that switch

Comment: @charlietfl I could change the switch method to something else if there is a better way (which I am sure there is). If you want to recommend a way please do. I was going to add leap years as well, but I felt the need to fix my mistakes before I continued to work on the calculator.

Comment: To get #days in given month ... `new Date(year, (monthIndex+1), 0).getDate()` ... https://jsfiddle.net/s90verp5/

Answer (score 1):

```
opti.text = id === "day" || "year" ? i.toString() : monthsarray[i-1];
```

Year is truthy, so monthsarray will never be taken as value. Do this:

```
opti.text = id === "day" || id==="year" ? i.toString() : monthsarray[i-1];
```

Also you dont want

```
switch(SelectObject){
```

You want to switch on its value:

```
switch(SelectObject.options[SelectObject.selectedIndex].value){
```

Mistake three

```
select.add(opi) => select.appendChild(opi)
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue about the months not displaying as text is now fixed, changing SelectObject to SelectObject.value did not fix the other issue unfortunately.

Comment: @David http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript

Comment: I tried both SelectObject.selected[SelectObject.selectedIndex].value, and SelectObject.options[SelectObject.selectedIndex].value. Still not working for some reason, but could it be because of my switch cases? I changed from select.add(opi) to select.appenChild(opi).

Comment: No errors. I am using notepad++ unfortunately, and I am going to change that tonight I think.

Comment: @David open in firefox/chrome. Right click. Inspect Element. Console. Has nothing to do with notepad++ ...